List all tables within a select statement in Snowflake
I have query in Snowflake that is near a thousand line. Is there a way to easily see what tables are accessed to easily list it? This will need to be done for many files, so if there is a quick & easy way to list all the tables it would be wonderful.

If the query has been executed, you can just look it up in Access History by query_id and see all of the tables and/or views that are leveraged (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history)

If you have query_ids for these queries. You can probably get them using access_history snowflake account_usage table. Look here for access history view details, and you probably need GOVERNANCE_VIEWER database role to access snowflake.account_usage.access_history table

select
    boa.value:"objectName" as table_name
from snowflake.account_usage.access_history
, lateral flatten(base_objects_accessed) boa
where query_id = '<query_id>'
and  boa.value:"objectDomain"::string='Table';



Create a view based on the query and then use lineage: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-lineage
